# "Get Publish profile" on Azure App service

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Please is there a kind of role that I can give to someone that uses my App services and he will not be able to have access to the **"Get Publish Profile"** . Is there a way I can restrict access to the "Get Publish Profile" tab.

I have tried the Microsoft.Web/sites/publishxml/Action  to a custom role, but the users still have access to the tab.

Please your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing by your phrasing that you found [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/609214/is-it-possible-to-restrict-access-to-34get-publish.html) and its accepted answer - can you confirm that you have taken **all** the actions mentioned i.e. 1) assign the permission to a custom role 2) assign that role to the user group you wish to block 3) create a [deny assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments) to that role on the app service?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there a way I can restrict access to the "Get Publish Profile" tab?
```

No, there isn't a built-in role like  [WebSite Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#website-contributor)  that you can set to restrict access to the Get Publish Profile.

But you can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) to either allow or deny  `Microsoft.Web/sites/publishxml/Action`  using custom role , which is the preferred method and then assign the role to the designated users.